# Bootstrap tooltip : overflow?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

## [My codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxPaJO)

I do not know how to get my tooltip out of the container.
I was forced to put an overflow: hidden so that the ripple effect does not come out of the block, but the tooltip is also impacted.

I tried this code but it did not work:

```
.tooltip { overflow: visible !important)
```

An idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options), you can append `.tooltip` to another element like (`body`).

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
```

Here is updated [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZxKvJ):

Answer (score 4):

From [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#usage) too, you can set

```
$('#example').tooltip({ boundary: 'window' })
```

Comment: You saved me I was looking everywhere.